# What interface should my service return? IQueryable, IList, IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net

Imagine I have a SearchService layer that has a method to search all cars starting with a certain string;

```
public static class Searcher{
    public IAnInterface<Car> CarsStartingWith(string startWith){
        //magic
    }
}
```

What interface should my service use?
IQueryable can render for a nice fluid interface in the rest of my application.
IEnumerable has the lazy aspect going with it.
IList is just the most practical.

I would like to have all my services return the same interface for consistency makes the whole thing a lot easier.
ICollection could maybe be an option too, but it just offers so little...

Comment: Almost duplicate discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396513/should-parameters-returns-of-collections-be-ienumerablet-or-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all your services to return the same interface then I would probably go for `IEnumerable<>`.

It'll be easy enough for your callers to convert to `IQueryable` or create a `List`, if necessary:

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars = Searcher.CarsStartingWith("L");
var carsList = cars.ToList();
var queryableCars = cars.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Completely agree. You should always use the minimum contract that's required. IEnumerable<T> can be consumed or converted by many BCL types, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: True. I decided to return IEnumerable. And if a IList makes more sense in a particular case, I will use a naming convention to make those methods stand out from the crowd.

Comment: The issue with returning `IEnumerable<T>` is if you decide you want to convert it to `IQuerable<T>` you are no longer querying against the DB, but against objects in memory. As James Curran pointed out `IQueryable` is a bit hefty, but in most my scenarios, I find offering a queryable set back is better an let the consumer decide if they want to down cast it to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose `IEnumerable` because it has a more central place in the framework, providing versatility for those that need it, while also providing familiarity to those who are yet to get stuck into things like LINQ.

Comment: I like IEnumerable, if only there was a way to give it a Count method. I know it is inherent to being lazy to not know how many there are, but the Count property is just something you need so many times!

Comment: LINQ provides a Count extension method for IEnumerable.

Comment: @Jeff not a good idea if the original was an IQueryable (it would be retrieved and Counted).

Comment: That is true, but that wasn't what was asked. Any deferred execution makes this difficult. Any Count is likely to do the retrieval, regardless of the interface, so I think your point is moot in light of the need for a Count property.

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb is as follows:

If there is ever a chance that I can take the routine's core algorithm and refactor it in a way that I can use yield returns, I will go with IEnumerable<T>.

For example, if my current implementation uses an array or a List<T> internally, but I know that, at least theoretically, I may want to and be capable of reworking it internally to do lazy evaluation, I'll return an IEnumerable<T>.

I've found that the gains of returning IEnumerable<T> are definitely worth the hassle of using it.

However, if the algorithm, in its very nature, is going to need to fully evaluate the results before returning (rare, but does happen), I will go with an IList<T>.  Basically, if I'm already computing it, I'll return it.  IList<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, so all of the LINQ-related use cases still work, but you lose the lazy evaluation.  If I'm already forced to evaluate in advance, that's not a problem, though.

I rarely return IQueryable.  The only time I would use this interface is if I'm directly creating a queryable data access layer, or something similar.  The overhead of using this is, in most cases, not worth the gains.

However, if your goal is to always use a single interface (I don't necessarily agree with this goal), I would stick to IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 2):

`IQueryable` would have a rather heavy requirement on it -- you couldn't, for example, return an array.

Usually for me, the choice between `IEnumerable` or `IList` usually ends up being whichever is easier to implement in the standard case.

Comment: Same for me so far. But I'm trying to become a bit more consistent in my programming style. And I thought I'd throw IQueryable in because fluid interfaces usually look very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It depends.

Longer answer: Return the richest type that your client code is going to need. IList works in most cases if you don't need lazy loading. You can still use Linq to query against an IList or IEnumerable. If lazy loading is a requirement, then go with IEnumerable or IQueryable.

Side note: Returning the same interface for all services might seem like a noble goal but given different client usage patterns, you may want to return different interfaces.

Comment: True, maybe a naming convention depending ont he lazy/non-lazy could be interesting.

Comment: I'd argue the other way around. IList provides way more than IEnumerable and so you should choose IEnumerable, regardless of lazy evaluation, unless you need additional methods like Add, Remove, and indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Always go with `IEnumerable` unless you have a serious reason not to. You can then implement the getter with `yield return`.

`IQueryable` is a totally different kettle of fish. Not something you'd casually implement as an alternative to a typical in-memory container.

Of the rest, there is a major different between `IEnumerable` and the others: it's readonly.

Comment: Casting a return value to IEnumerable doesn't make it readonly: it can be cast back again by the called.  If you want readonly, wrap the result in a readonly collection (e.g. using List(T).AsReadOnly) before returning it.  I usually return IList(T) or ICollection(T) as callers often want a count.

Comment: Of course - I mean it is statically typed so as to be readonly. You might as well say "There's no point making fields private - they can use reflection to get at them anyway".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IQueryable as return type, You have a service layer with leaky abstraction.